# Event tracking on a subdomain (already with extra parameters) - Universal Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

We offer an instant access which auto logs users into a demo account (of our CRM system).

I'm using event & conversion tracking in Google analytics to trigger when:

```
Category equal to: Instant-access
Action Equal to: Instant-access-sign-up
Label equal to: Instant-access-sign-up
Value equal to: 35
```

The original link looks like:

```
https://secure.workbooks.com/login?demo=1
```

*Link auto signs users into a demo account.*

So the link I've created (event tracking added onto link to track) is:

```
https://secure.workbooks.com/login?demo=1?onClick="ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'Instant-access', eventAction: 'Instant-access-sign-up', eventLabel: 'Instant-access-sign-up', eventValue: 35
```

However this doesn't seem to be working. Any idea what it is that's not working?

I've provided my links as code, since they provide no value as *links* as we're studying the link parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onclick is an attribute on an element, not something you can add to a URL.

If you want to track the event on the page you are on when you click the link, you do:

```
<a href="/demo/" onclick="ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'Instant-access', eventAction: 'Instant-access-sign-up', eventLabel: 'Instant-access-sign-up', eventValue: 35});">my demo</a>
```

If the tracking you are targeting is on the demo page itself, the pageview should be fine for a goal.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, shame you can't do this with campaign tracking. I'm using hubspot and can only fill in an actual URL. Will look into alternative arrangements.

Comment: @Sam, You could prefix/suffix a campaign variable to the request url in an advanced filter if you need one, but I don't get why you aren't just using a page goal with a regex, ie "login.*demo" would be my goal and I would normally just segment on the different sources.

Comment: Hey buddy,

Both the landing page and destination page are on seperate subdomains. After visiting /login?demo=1 you are auto logged in (takes perhaps 2/3 seconds) which then leads to your final page. If I set-up the goal page as regex: /login?demo=1 with a required funnel page as /workbooks-instant-access will this still work? I've set it up in Analytics goals so time will tell (though it doesn't verify?).

Any other ideas? Another issue with event tracking is that the landing page is in Hubspot and I can't edit the form to add in the event tracking On Click attribute.

Comment: @Sam, I would have to know the exact relationships between the ~3 pages, (sub)domains, snippets?, independent UA accounts(?) to know what would happen as far as using them in a funnel. But if you are trying to limit the goal to specific source links, you should be able to just add another parameter as long as your login ignores them, i.e. `/login?demo=1&campaign=hubspot1` You could also do this 'properly' with the utm campaign builder but that will blow away existing source information which is a bad idea if this is advertising across subdomains of your own site?

Comment: Thanks Lossleader, would I then set this up as an event conversion with the campaign hubspot1.

Comment: Thanks Lossleader, unfortunately I have just uncovered that my analytics view filters out visits to secure.workbooks.com and since that link would be: secure.workbooks.com/login?demo=1&campaign=hubspot1 they'd never be counted. Unless I create the goal on a separate view. I think this maybe my only option since Hubspot seems unflexable to add in event tracking.